# Drupal 7 setting different Hosts for different request headers

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 website, some resources are being requests with the Host set to have the www prefix while others are not.

- https://www.example.com *when request header is 301 Moved Permanently*
- https://example.com     *when request header is 304 Not Modified*

Changing the base_url does not appear to modify the behaviour.

Is there anyway I can make drupal set the Host as https://example.com for all the request headers?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [Apache wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CanonicalHostNames), which shows a solution to your requirement. The first solution uses a virtual host setup and the [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive

```
# Redirect every request to example.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.net
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

# Define virtual host for example.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

And the second setup uses a [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

You can choose whichever fits your environment best.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I did not try this because we found the solution.
Our host was pointing at "localhost", by setting this to 127.0.0.1 the problem resolved.